Missing MaybeSerializeDeserialize trait on AssetId
Like many other pallets we use an AssetId, set to the associated type AssetId of the Inspect trait (ref). The problem I'm facing is that I need to set the genesis with assets yet this AssetId type of Inspect isn't bounded by the MaybeSerializeDeserialize trait (the Balance type is (ref)).
One solution is to bound the AssetId type with the MaybeSerializeDeserialize, or add it to supertrait AssetId. This however causes many errors in other pallets and is probably not going to be an easy solution (if it sounds like a good idea please shout, I can submit a PR to polkadot sdk).
Another solution is to create a wrapper but then I need to manually implement the MaybeSerializeDeserialize trait on it.
Is there another solution that I'm missing here?

A where clause did the trick!
    #[pallet::genesis_config]
    #[derive(frame_support::DefaultNoBound)]
    pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config>
    where
        <T::Assets as Inspect<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::AssetId:
            MaybeSerializeDeserialize,
    {
        #[serde(skip)]
        pub _config: PhantomData<T>,
        pub assets_genesis: Vec<(AssetIdOf<T>, BalanceOf<T>)>,
    }


Please mark this as the answer.
